# deploying create-react-app app to github pages builds fine but won't deploy

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router, react-redux, github-pages

I have a react app created using create-react-app. It runs fine with no errors on my local host.

I have a repository for it on github and I am on the master branch. when I run npm run deploy the app builds with no issues but then when it comes to deployment I get the following messages:

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-11T22_02_32_295Z-debug.log
```

the complete log is here below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Gaz\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@5.7.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: my-app@0.1.0
6 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: PATH: C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Gaz\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Gaz\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: CWD: C:\my-app
9 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
10 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~predeploy: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: my-app@0.1.0
12 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\my-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Gaz\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Gaz\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
14 verbose lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: C:\my-app
15 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle my-app@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: my-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gaz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
19 verbose pkgid my-app@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd C:\my-app
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Gaz\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v8.9.3
24 verbose npm  v5.7.1
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error my-app@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried adding a base name to the history in my connectedRouter (using react-router-redux), still the same error.

I updated the repository address to include my username and password credentials to rule out any logging in issues.

I renamed my repository back to its original name thinking possible this was the problem.

I also renamed the build folder created to docs and tried to run github pages that way, via the master/docs option on github (since there seems to be no option to manually choose the gh-pages branch like a lot of instructions say there is). I still did not have any luck. I do think that this is the way I will have to do it though as I have just realised when i do try and host the master/docs on github pages it does in fact show my react-app title on the browser tab but it does not load anything.

my package.json file can be seen below:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://gurtaj1.github.io/Site1",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "paginator": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

The repository is currently and originally called Site1.

What's going on here?

Is it to do with my actual app or the way in which I am trying to deploy it?

Comment: Hi aaqib. If I run `git config --global user.name` it just displays my name (not user name). `git config --global user.username` does however show my correct username and I am able to make pushes to my git repository with no issues.

Comment: you don't have a repo called site1

Comment: @azium I changed the repo name back to what I had changed it to again it is now KOV. And.. I managed to get it to work! I just came online now to update with my findings..

Answer (score 0):

So I have now managed to get my repo onto my github pages.

I did not do it with the deploy method but with the master/docs method I mentioned in my question (using the github UI to set that docs folder as the source for my github pages). see here https://blog.github.com/2016-08-17-simpler-github-pages-publishing/.

I think the fact that I had changed the repo name to original name when trying to get the deploy method to work and perhaps still using an old build/a build where I had not included a basename in my history, is what caused this method not to work when i first had tried.

I am satisfied with using this method and I believe this to be the popper method now, rather than the deployment method I was originally trying. 
Although I could not find a true source for this, the github UI indicates as such since, I saw some guidelines that tell you to select the gh-pages branch of your repo as the source for github pages, but this is no longer an option, at least not on my github repo it isn't.

I hope somebody else with the same issue can get some help from this.